# Hide buttons in WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form with 5 buttons. One is to browse file other to close form and rest of three for other functions. I want to hide those three buttons untill I click on browse button. Will that be possible? if so pls explain the procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a simple google search would do it.

Comment: there is a control property called `Visible` which is used for such behavior.

Comment: Do you have any event handlers implemented already? Could you show some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `Visible` property and event handlers to do it:

```
Button b1 = new Button();

Button b2 = new Button();
b2.Visible = false;

b1.Click = b1_Click;

private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b2.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Button.Visible=false;` for hiding the button.
In `Form_Load()`:

```
Button1.Visible=false;
Button2.Visible=false;
Button3.Visible=false;
```

In BrowseButton's Click_Event:

```
Button1.Visible=true;
Button2.Visible=true;
Button3.Visible=true;
```